# Sort 2 linked arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I want to sort one array and "mirror" order changes to another array of the same dimension.

The question is similar to this one but for Swift language:
[Better way to sort 2 "linked" arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251752/better-way-to-sort-2-linked-arrays)

Example:

```
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let arr2 = [1, 5, 9, 2, 3]
... //sort
//result == ["a", "d", "e", "b", c"]
```

Approximate solution I know:

```
for i in stride(from 0, to: arr2.count - 1, by: 1) {
  for j in stride(from i + 1, to: arr2.count, by: 1) {
    if arr2[i] > arr2[j] {
      ...//swap arr2[i] and arr2[j]
      ...//swap arr1[i] and arr1[j]
    }
  }
}
```

But they added a lot of additional possibilities for advanced working with arrays in Swift. So is it possible to simplify this solution with inner Swift features?

Note: `arr1` and `arr2` are given as separate arrays.

**EDITED**

Yes. You found the similar questions but their titles are awful and don't reflect the answers their authors need. In other words if you delete/close my question the people may continue to ask it again because it is impossible to find something with existing titles!

Comment: The proper solution is to have just one array. Define a `struct` and keep your data together properly.

Comment: @staticVoidMan yes, they ask the same thing. BUT in the same time they didn't couch their questions clearly (there is another duplicate question inside your link). `sort array based on array` sounds like 2 arrays with an inheritance-like relationship. `2 linked arrays` is clearer because these arrays have no explicit relationships and it will be easier to find with my title - I see you plan to close and delete my question

Comment: There is no plan to delete your question. It will remain closed as a duplicate. This is fine and not negative to you in any way. People doing a search may come across your question due to the better title. They will see the answer here and the link to the duplicate and all of its answers. Win-win for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `zip` the arrays together
- `sort` the new array by array 2
- `map` the array to array 1

  ```
  let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
  let arr2 = [1, 5, 9, 2, 3]

  let result = zip(arr1, arr2) // [("a", 1), ("b", 5), ("c", 9), ("d", 2), ("e", 3)]
                  .sorted(by: {$0.1 < $1.1}) // [("a", 1), ("d", 2), ("e", 3), ("b", 5), ("c", 9)]
                  .map{ $0.0 } // ["a", "d", "e", "b", "c"]
  ```

Comment: thanks. The only question I have is it possible to fix your code to access to tuples by name, not a number?

Comment: You could use the full syntax where the shorthands `$0 / $1` are represented by parameter labels. Use code completion and press `return` on the closure placeholder.